# Insert DataTable contents into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datagrid, insert

Hi all I am trying to take the data from my datagridveiw and insert into my SQL Server, but I am stuck at the inserting part, here is what I have so far

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        var fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        fdlg.Title = @"Site Assist Database Update";
        fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        fdlg.Filter = @"CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
        fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filepath = fdlg.FileName;
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<PartList>();
            engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;
            PartList[] res = engine.ReadFile(filepath);

            if (engine.ErrorManager.ErrorCount > 0)
                engine.ErrorManager.SaveErrors("Errors.txt");

            var table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Part Number", typeof (string));
            table.Columns.Add("Part Name", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("On Hand New", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("On Hand Fixed", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("SC5 - Storage Bin - EAME", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Is ASL Item", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Reorder Point", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Stock Maximum", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("On Order", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Back Order", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Part Cost", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("PC11 - Repairable - EAME", typeof(string));

            foreach (PartList row in res)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(row.PartNum, row.PartName, row.New, row.Fix, row.Location, row.ASL, row.ReorderPoint,
                               row.stockMax, row.OnOrder, row.BackOrder, CleanInput(row.Cost), row.Repairable);
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

            MessageBox.Show(table.Rows.Count.ToString());
        }
}
```

I have googled around and cant find any really good solid samples on how to achieve this.

`SqlBulkCopy` is a option but again I will hold my hands up and say I don't know how to do this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using foreach for insert gridview data into sql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185800/using-foreach-for-insert-gridview-data-into-sql-database)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6185836/843327

So once you have the data in your datatable, gridview, etc (whatever really) you need to do a foreach loop on each row of that table. Inside the foreach you will have your SqlConnection, SqlCommand,SqlParameters, and execution.

The link should provide the right info! Hope it helps!

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the SqlBulkCopy object it is important that your DataTable object has the same schema as the target database table. If you are dealing with a lot of row, this is a good approach. If not, it's probably better to use a normal SQL INSERT query.

Attached some code to show a method for using SqlBulkCopy. Note that the schema of the local DataTable (MyDataTable) is filled from the database. This ensures you have the same schema and avoid cumbersome setup using code.

```
DataTable MyDataTable = new DataTable();          

// this section will get the schema of your target table without retriving any data
using(SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection("a connection string")) {                
    string getSchemaSql = "SELECT * FROM MyDatabaseTable WHERE 1 = 0";            
    SqlDataAdapter A = new SqlDataAdapter(getSchemaSql, MyConnection);
    MyConnection.Open();
    A.FillSchema(MyDataTable, SchemaType.Source);
}

// add your information to MyDataTable
foreach (PartList row in res) {
    MyDataTable.Rows.Add(row.PartNum, row.PartName, row.New, row.Fix, row.Location, row.ASL, row.ReorderPoint, row.stockMax, row.OnOrder, row.BackOrder, CleanInput(row.Cost), row.Repairable); 
}

// assign MyDataTable as your DataGridView source
dataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataTable;

// export MyDataTable to the DBMS database table
using(SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection("a connection string")) {                
    SqlBulkCopy TheBulkCopier = new SqlBulkCopy(MyConnection);                
    TheBulkCopier.DestinationTableName = "MyDatabaseTable";
    MyConnection.Open();
    TheBulkCopier.WriteToServer(MyDataTable);
}
```