# want to add data to grid view row according to the value of first cell row input,which event should i used and how in C#

Tags: c#

I m trying to fetch data according to the value of first cell of each row ,I tried for `CellBeginEdit` in C#  but it's not done bye me, so please help

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, 
 DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {

        string text="";
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
            text += cell.Value.ToString();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
```

Comment: Check the following link below.
[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185800/using-foreach-for-insert-gridview-data-into-sql-database

Comment: Thank you for your response, but actually my aim is to create gridview having 4 coloumns as i enter barcode in first cell of row its fatch data from one table of database  according to barcode and  
show in that row and save it to another table of database and control should move to first cell of next row and above procedure will be repeate